# Should I have both Transaction Log Backups and Log Shipping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, transaction-log, log-shipping

I set my database to Full Recovery a few months ago (to allow point-in-time restores) and set up Transaction Log backups with Maintenance Plan.

Now we want to conduct Log Shipping with the same database. In Log shipping setup, it asks for Source Transaction Log Backups, and then the usual copy to Destination Server and Restores, etc.

If I set up Log Shipping Transaction Log Backups, then I will have two transaction log backups. From setting the database to full recovery, and then log shipping.

(a) Is this is not repetitive? Should I remove the original transaction log backup in Maintenance Plan or the one from Log Shipping?

(b) Or perhaps the Log Shipping Transaction Log Backup does not clear out/truncate the Transaction Log ldf file like Maintenance Plan does?

Comment: No, the DBMS is mentioned in the body of the question and in the tags. That is enough

Comment: I assure you. Even just the "Log shipping" is not generic. 95% of the [questions tagged or mentioning "log shipping"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=Log+Shipping) are about SQL Server and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only have one stream of log backups, and that would of course in this situation be your log shipping backups. If you keep doing log backups in your maint plan, then the log shipping restore will fail as soon as maint plan log backup was done "in between" two log shipping log backups. A: Remove the log backups from your maint plans. B: Yes, it does - it is a regular log backup, after all.

Comment: In addition to: Maybe try maintenance plan add parameter to COPY_ONLY.

Check it : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/copy-only-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I very much doubt that COPY_ONLY backups in maint plans would be useful. Those maint plan backups will be broken by the log shipping backups (since the log shipping backups will truncate the log) and useless without the log shipping backups.